# "Key" object in jQuery does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been trying to get this small bit of code to work. However, I'm not sure if it's my syntax or if I have done this incorrectly. The goal of this code is for the user to input a string like `"H2" or "Li"` and return the number associated with that string in the div "testing."  When I run the code, it does not return anything.

```
<form>
            <input type="text" name="atomNameOne"/> 
</form>
        <button name="moleRatios">Submit!</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <div id="testing"></div>
```

This is the `jQuery` code associated with my code.

```
 $('button[name=moleRatios]').click(function(){
    var compound = {
    H2 = 2.01594,
    Li = 6.939,
    Be = 9.0122,
    B = 10.811
    }

    var search = function(name) {
        for(var key in compound) {
            if(compound[key] === name) {
            return compound[key];
            }
        }
    };


    var $atomValueOne = search($('input[name=atomNameOne]').val());


    $('#testing').text($atomValueOne);

    });
```

Comment: it look like this way `var compound = {
H2: 2.01594,
Li : 6.939,
Be: 9.0122,
B : 10.811,
}`

Comment: Also you don't need a `for` loop to search through the `compound` object.

Comment: Why? I thought that's how you look through a "dictionary" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a wrong syntax there:

```
var compound = {
H2 = 2.01594,
Li = 6.939,
Be = 9.0122,
B = 10.811
}
```

should be

```
var compound = {
H2: 2.01594,
Li: 6.939,
Be: 9.0122,
B: 10.811
}
```

and then

compound[key] will return 2.01594 if key is H2, maybe you want

```
if(compound[key] === name)
```

to be

```
if(key == name)
```

instead
The rest should be the same

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the problem all along!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if(compound[key] === name)
```

with

```
if(key === name)
```

and also correct the object syntax as given in other answers

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to define an object is

```
var compound = { H2: 2.01594, Li : 6.939, Be: 9.0122, B : 10.811 }
```

as a **propertyName : propertyValue** format. 
To access the propertyName as a string, use-

```
var search = function(name) {
    for(var key in compound) {
        if(key === name) {
        return compound[key];
        }
    }
};
```

where the iterator 'key' will always give the name(as a string) of the property and the format **objectName[iterator]** will always give the value of the property.